# Country ranking by combination of factors

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I'm trying to find the most correct way of ranking countries based on multiple factors with measurements in different units. Take the following example:

I am comparing $4$ countries nl.:
United States,
China,
Australia,
South Africa

And trying to create a composite ranking system based on their values of the following factors: 
GDP (measured in billion US$\$$), 
GDP (Measured in %), 
Population (measured in millions), 
Health ($1$ is worst, $10$ is best)

By combining these factors for each country, I wan't to rank them from best to worst.

The one way I can see of doing this is by adding all of their values together for e.g. GDP and then dividing each individual country by the total. Then move on to the next, i.e. GDP and then population etc. etc.

The whole thing feels like comparing apples with oranges though, and it doesn't feel like it gives an accurate indication.

Does someone else perhaps have an answer?

Comment: "GDP per capita" makes more sense than distinct "GDP" and "population". Then you actually could sum it up (with an weigthed avg. for example)

Comment: hi @adjan. Thanks so much for suggestion. However, say we are stuck with those factors. I don't have a choice on what factors will be used. For this purpose can we apply something like weighted average when measured in different units?

Comment: Your weighting would certainly need to correct the obvious scale problem in the units ($3$ points more in health hardly signifies against $50$ million more in population, say).  But, more difficultly, you would need to decide what the offsets should be.  How many dollars per person in wealth is worth a point in health?  (mind you, I don't see any way, even in principle, to ask how many extra people are worth a point in health.  those seem radically incommensurate).

Comment: "The Age of Nations is past. The task before us now, if we would not perish, is to build the Earth."
-- Teilhard de Chardin

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately your question is more of a philosophical one rather than a mathematical one. You could take any existing metric suitable for vectors and apply it to your data. Each one would rank the countries but whether any of the ways are useful, meaningful or 'correct' is quite another matter. I would reccomend looking at the measures commonly used in economics, sociology and similar subjects who deal specifically with this type of data.

I would also recommend considering visual methods. E.g. for the four quantities above you could have population on the x-axis, health on the y-axis and for a given country the values for these are given as two half circles centred at the relevant point in x-y for that country. Then one half circle gives the relative value of GDP in $ and the other half circle gives it in %.

Here is an example of what I mean http://visual.ly/co2-emissions-gdp-and-population-bubble-charts.